# Rails Chartkick Gem Error Loading Chart No Adapter Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app where I'm using the `chartkick` and `groupdate` gem to try to generate some basic charts.

When I load my view I get the error:
`Error Loading Chart: No adapter found`

Here's what my view code looks like:

**index.html.erb**

`<%= line_chart Call.group_by_week(:created_at).count %>`

Here's my application layout including chartkick and yielding chart_js
**application.html.erb (layout)**

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "chartkick" %>
 <%= yield :charts_js %>
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?  I'd really like to start using Chartkick to generate some simple charts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably you missed loading Google Charts or Highcharts (the adapters).

Try adding this line `<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi" %>` before `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "chartkick" %>`. Also check the Installation section in gem's home page (scroll down :)).

Comment: I did miss calling the Google Charts.  I figured it out already.  But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank you, mr. Sherif!

Answer (score 6):

To View:
Google Charts
In your layout or views, add:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
```

link: https://chartkick.com/#google-charts

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue as well when I first tried out [ChartKick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick). The error message that I got is **Error Loading Chart: No charting libraries found - be sure to include one before your charts**

Here's how I fixed it.

I simply added the following line of code below to the **application.js** file in the **assets > javascript** folder.

```
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
```

Save and refresh, that should fix it.

That's all

**I hope this helps.**

Comment: not working for me. i have been following that since the beginning

Answer (score 2):

Another cause of error can be the protocol you use in the javascript_include_tag.

For instance you will get the error `Error Loading Chart: No adapter found` 
if you for instance use protocol https for your website: `https://www.example.com`

and http in the javascript_include_tag in your code:
`<%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>`

Answer (score 1):

If above doesn't solve for someone, one additional possibility is a `mixed content` issue.

You can check this by opening the JS console.

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://site.io/' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/jsapi'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Solution:**

Just change this

```
http://www.google.com/jsapi
```

To this (add `s` to `http`)

```
https://www.google.com/jsapi
```